# Metric vs PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, metric-spaces

What is the relation between a positive semidefinite matrix (a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues are nonnegative) and a metric matrix (a matrix with triangle inequality, symmetry, and zero on the main diagonal)?

My intuition says there is some relation between these two....

Comment: What is a triangle inequality on a matrix?

Comment: Triangle inequality for a matrix $M$ says  $M(i, j) \le M(i,k) + M(k, j)$ for any i,j, k.

Comment: In general these are quite  different, but Schoenberg-type theorems describe isometric embeddability of a metric space in terms of PSD-like conditions on a certain transform of the distance matrix. See [Distance matrices and isometric embeddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.2063) for example.

Comment: @user4412195 . Thanks!